# How to use guava cache load function with a limit time?

Tags: java, caching, guava

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
             public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
               return createExpensiveGraph(key);
             }
           });
```

The `createExpensiveGraph` method may take a long time to return a value. I want set a time limit within the `load` method, so that if the `createExpensiveGraph` method hasn't returned a value in the limited time, a `TimeLimitedException` is thrown. How can I set a time limit in the `load` method?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** corrected to use `newSingleThreadExecutor` as [pointed out by eclps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170948/697449).

You could use a [`Callable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to implement the timeout behavior:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

final LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
       .maximumSize(1000)
       .build(
           new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
               public Graph load(final Key key) throws Exception {
                   return executor.submit(new Callable<Graph>() {
                       @Override
                       public Graph call() {
                           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
                       }
                   }).get(MY_TIME_LIMIT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
               }
           });
```

And at the `get` call site:

```
final Graph graph;
try {
    graph = graphs.get(myKey);
}
catch (ExecutionException executionException) {
    final Throwable cause = Throwables.getRootCause(executionException);
    if (cause instanceof TimeoutException) {
        // timeout specific logic
    }
    // other error handling
}

// use graph
```

Answer (score 4):

Paul Bellora's example as written will not work because of `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()`.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#sameThreadExecutor%28%29) for `MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor()`:

> Tasks are run to completion before a Future is returned to the caller (unless the executor has been shutdown).

Therefore the `get` on the Future will not be called until after `createExpensiveGraph` completes execution. Use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` or a similar Executor to support timeouts.

Comment: Nice catch (though it took me 5 years to notice). Corrected, thanks!